# Can't simplify this fraction: $ \frac{1+x^6}{1+x^2}$

Tags: polynomials, fractions

I've been having trouble simplifying this fraction :
$$
\frac{1+x^6}{1+x^2}
$$

Can anyone explain step by step on how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: @T.Bongers I've been using Microsoft Mathematics and It says that the result of this fraction is `x^4-x^2+1`

Comment: @looky Yes, you're right. Try using a sum of cubes formula on top, since $1 + x^6 = 1^3 + (x^2)^3 = (1 + x^2)(1 - x^2 + (x^2)^2)$

Comment: Can you compute $(1+y^3)/(1+y)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Here :) `y^2-y+1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$1+x^6=1+({x^2})^3$ which is equivalent to

$(1+x^2)(x^4+1-x^2)$ using $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$

Hence the expression becomes $$\frac{(1+x^2)(x^4+1-x^2)}{1+x^2} = (x^4+1-x^2).$$

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

For this rational function, or any other rational function, you can use [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) to simplify it. In this case there is no remainder as $x^2 + 1$ is a factor of $x^6 + 1$, but if you didn't know that beforehand, you will find that out by applying long division.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try it in Maple to find the desire insight for simplifying the fraction. This would be just a start point:

```
    [> factor(x^6+1);
                              (1+x^2)*(x^4-x^2+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple, you can let $x^2+1=a$. Then $1+x^6= a(a^2-a+1)$. Hence $\dfrac{x^6+1}{x^2+1}=a^2-a+1= x^4-x^2+1$.